# Prove the sum of two vector of an endomorphism space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I have a question about linear algebra,

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space and $\phi \in End_{\mathbb{R}}(V)$. Let $v,w \in V$

Prove $<v>_{\phi} +<w>_{\phi} = <v-w>_{\phi} + <v+w>_{\phi} $

in which $<.>_\phi$ is a cyclic subspace. Thanks to Mr.DonAntonio.

I tried to use the definition of Endomorphism (linearity), but I failed.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Sorry for making things unclear, I have already reedited it.

Comment: What is $\;\langle v\rangle_\phi\;$ ? The image of $\;v\;$ under $\;\phi\;$ ...or something else?

Comment: $<v>\phi$ means the subspace of V generated by vector $v$, and $\phi$ is a linear application, sorry for not mentioned that. @DonAntonio

Comment: I still can't understand: you seem to imply that $\;\langle v\rangle=\text{Span}\{v\}\;$ , and this is fine. What has this to do with the linear map $\;\phi\;$ ? Why does it appear as subindex there, $\;\langle\cdot\rangle_\phi\;$ ...??

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't know how people represent it in other universities, but what we learned it's the subspace generated by v after the linear map $\phi$. I don't know why our prof used $<.>_\phi$ to represent it.

Comment: Then that notation must mean something else...and I've no idea what it could be. Even the phrase "subspace generated by $\;v\;$ after the linear map $\;\phi\;$" doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: @DonAntonio Excuse me, I hope it won't be bothering, so I checked my lecture note about this, and the definition is "for $v \in V$, we have $<v>_\phi :=<\phi^{i}(v) |i \in \mathbb{N}>$, The subspace of V is generated by $v, \phi(v), \phi^{2}(v),...$" I hope I didn't explain it wrong, and again sorry for making things unclear.

Comment: Thanks, that now makes all the sense of the world. That's called on this site of the galaxy "cyclic subspace". Good, at least now I understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try double inclusion: since $\;\phi^k(u\pm w)=\phi^kv\pm\phi^k w\;$ , we have that

$$\begin{cases}\phi^k v=\cfrac12\left(\phi^k(v-w)+\phi^k(v+w)\right)\\{}\\
\phi^kw=\cfrac12\left(\phi^k(v+w)-\phi^k(v-w)\right)\end{cases}$$

and we thus get the inclusion $\;\langle v\rangle_\phi+\langle w\rangle_\phi\subset\langle v+w\rangle_\phi+\langle v-w\rangle_\phi\;$

A hint for the other inclusion: we have that

$$\phi^k(v-w)=\phi^kv-\phi^kw\in\langle v\rangle_\phi+\langle w\rangle_\phi\;\ldots$$

Comment: Thank you very much!  and again sorry for making things unclear.